# Windshield repair with no shade

Tags: repair, windshield

I have a "Bull's-Eye" crack in my windshield. I'm planning on repairing it with the Rain-X Windshield Repair kit, but I don't have a garage or any good shaded spots where I can do the repair. I've considered two options, and would like opinions on if either of them will work.

1. Prop up an umbrella to block the sun from the windshield while I'm doing the repair.
2. Do the repair at night, and just leave the car in the driveway until morning.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think either would work, but there are drawbacks.

As far as using an umbrella, is it going to continuously provide you the shade while you work? Or will you need to be shifting it as the sun moves? On consideration here is you might consider getting a 10x10 canopy to work under. They are fairly cheap and easily collapsible for storage. You should be able to work under it for the entire time you're trying to fix the windshield.

As far as working at night, when it becomes dark (or darker), it becomes harder to see what you're doing. Instead of complete darkness, you might consider doing it at dusk or dawn. Either way, you'll have a lot of time with light present which is not direct sunlight.